# Internship seeker :P

Tags: internships, site, jobs, job

Hey there!anyone knows of any site where companies regularly post interniship or job positions required?

United states-Canada-

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Mandy.com or craigslist.org (in both the Jobs/Film and Television and the Gigs sections). However, a sound post internship will only appear on either of these sites once in a blue moon. You'd be much better served researching all the studios out there, and approaching them yourself.

Also, i just noticed you're from Guatemala; if you're not a US resident, you might have a very hard time getting a studio to sponsor you for an internship visa. If you post more details about your situation we may be able to help more, but it's a tough industry to crack into.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks!

 Yes, I am indeed from Guatemala and have considered the visa issue, that's why I was also looking for a job, the chance of getting sponsored would be much greater with a job, but anyways, I know :(, its hard to crack in and its harder when you live in a country like mine where there is no industry at all...there is nothing I can crack into here :/.


Comment: @spoons_r_better It does sound like a tough situation... Maybe try to search out any kind of production company at all there, anyone who produces audiovisual content. Some experience is better than no experience! And i'm not sure how your Portugese is, but it seems there is some work in Brazil, Mexico might be a good idea too. I have no idea about politics in Central America though, so i'm sure you know your opportunities better than i do.

Comment: @Roger Middenway Hey thanks!I am indeed digging and digging, I just finished working on a film and I saw my name on the credits in a theatre screen for the first time in my life, plus, ofcourse, I heard my work at a real theatre; it feels pretty amazing! and you are totally right, some experience is better than nothing, so I will keep working hard on what I can :)
